Can you say “you have no morality” to criticize somebody who’s immoral?

Can you say “you have no morality” to criticize somebody who’s immoral? (I don’t mean sexually.) I want to use a noun instead of an adjective like “immoral”.
When you want to say somebody has no morals, how do you say it idiomatically? Thank you.


Of course you can.

To me it sounds more like an amoral person than an immoral person.

So is "amoral" more idiomatic than "immoral"?

@abcd, no, it's not a matter of idiomaticity; the two words simply have different meanings. There is a difference between not thinking in moral terms (when moral thinking is called for), and having moral views that are wrong.


I thought Peter above meant the pronunciation of the word. That's why I replied. 2. "Immoral" means "not following accepted standards of morality", so one can know what's right and wrong, but simply doesn't follow them.


Sorry about the confusion. I did not realise the idiom "sounds like" would be misunderstood. I meant that "has no morality", which is a slightly unusual expression, suggests to me one who is amoral rather than one who is immoral.

How would you criticize somebody who’s immoral then?

@abcd, by offering moral counterarguments to whatever arguments the person has for behaving immorally. In any event, this site is not the right place for extensive metaethical discussion of the differences among being amoral, being immoral, and being weak-willed (a concept that you have alluded to in one of your comments); what is within the scope of this site is to just observe, as Peter did, that 'you have no morals' is more apt as a characterisation of amorality than of immorality (even though it is also true that, in casual conversations, people are not attentive to such distinctios).

@jsw29, no. I didn't want to discuss ethics in this forum. I know what this forum is for. As I said in this post, I just want to know the idiomatic way to say "you have no morality" in one sentence.

It would be more usual to say "You have no morals."

standards for good or bad character and behavior:


"You lack a moral compass."
https://www.merriam-webster.com/dictionary/moral%20compass
https://dictionary.cambridge.org/dictionary/english/moral-compass
